# Couldn't chown to remote NAS box

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs

I have a NAS drive connected to one of my servers w/NFSv3. The problem is, a while ago some of the numeric UID's have changed on the system and those users are no longer able to access their files on the NAS drive.

This got me thinking and I created a file as root and then chowned it to my ID and to my surprise, I was not able to access it.

What I understood was, the file "go_in_to" the drive with a certain ID and it stays this way no matter if root chowns it from client side. I have never seen this before; but root should not be squashed because when root tries to read, it can read all the files, and when root chowns it reflects correctly on "ls -l", but still user cannot access.

Next step I did was, I-- with my id--open that file again with vim editor, obviously got a "read_only" flag, then I tried forcing the write with wq!, and this unlocked the file for me, and I was able to access it again. This happened because apparently vim creates a new file if forced to write, so this new file carries my ID this time, not the root's.

But the problem is, there are many files on that drive and I cannot go around forcing write on all of them, to make things worse, the NAS box is something I do not have access to.

Is this a known behavior from NAS point of view.

Comment: does an `ls -l` show a trailing plus `+` after the UGO file permissions like `-rw-r--r--+ 1 root root  100 Mar 15 10:33 filename` indicating alternate access methods?

Comment: No, just the normal UGO